GitKraken: Fetching pull requests failed. Remotes changed during action
In Gitkraken this error keeps popping up whenever we do a pull or fetch: "Fetching pull requests failed. Remotes changed during action".
Not sure where to look. Gitkraken's error messages are pretty short.
It hasnt always been like this.
We are using Azure Devops, we are connected to Azure Devops.
This happens both with an PAT and via SSH.
The origin is https://org@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/reponame or https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/reponame.
Gitkraken's Launchpad-tab is showing the Pull Requests from Azure.


This seems related to the repo being a fork. The original repo has been removed.
